# Use ant (build.xml) to compile jni directory

Tags: android, ant, build-automation

I'm using ant to build my android app (`ant compile`, `ant install` and so on) and I'm adding some NDK sources (inside `jni/` directory) and I want to have a rule to recompile the `jni/` directory with ant and THEN install my app into my device/emulator, like this:

```
$ ant jni-and-install
```

Instead of:

```
$ make -f jni/Makefile APP=myapp    
(jni compilation & installation)
...
$ ant install
```

I was trying to find the place to put my rules in build.xml but I don't know where.

What should I edit for ant to call `make` on `jni/` directory before installing into device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [exec ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) :

```
<target name="install">
    <!-- ... -->
</target>

<target name="jni">
    <exec executable="make">
        <arg line="-f jni/Makefile APP=myapp"/>
    </exec>
</target>

<target name="jni-and-install" depends="jni, install"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an exec ant task for this. I think putting the following in your `-pre-build` target in build.xml will do the trick:

```
<exec executable="make" failonerror="true">
    <arg line="-f jni/Makefile APP=myapp"/>
</exec>
```

Edit: JB's solution allows for things like `ant jni` to build the jni code without building the rest of your project.  You can get the best of both worlds by wrapping the above in a target named "jni" and then adding `depends="jni"` to your -pre-build target.